# Sequence and table with the same name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

Can we have a sequence and table with the same name? I am trying to create a sequence with the same name as an existing table, but I get this error:

> There is already an object named 'XYZ' in the database.

I haven't found any documentation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An attempt to document this is made here:

[CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

> *sequence_name*
>   Specifies the unique name by which the sequence is known in the
>   database.

It is not very clear that the name must be unique across **all objects** in the database. And even that is not true. The name must be unique within the schema in a database.